# Query formatting

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have table with below rows

> #### Name Month Salary Expense
>
> John    Jan      1000    50 
>   
>   John    Feb      5000      2000
>   
>   Jack    Jan      3000      100

I want to get output in the below format. How to achieve this.

> #### Name   JAN   FEB
>
> John   1000 50   5000 2000
>   
>  Jack   3000 100   0     0

Comment: please format your output. Its not all clear what is required output

Comment: do you want a Sql query or you want to do it from C#

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

This sql(-server) query would work:

```
select name,
  isnull(max(case when month='jan' then salary end), 0) as Salary_jan,
  isnull(max(case when month='feb' then salary end), 0) as Salary_feb
  -- and so on
group by name
```

Comment: Months are dynamic. Its not always jan and feb. I will just get date range as input.